# aws cli returning unknown options on create-image command

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am running below command to create ami from existing ec2 server with tags. Below is the command I am using to run on redhat linux 8.3

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $instance_id --name "$ami_name" --region $region --description "$desc" --no-reboot --tags-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key='Owner',Value='Some_one'},{Key='Environment',Value='Production:Dev'},{Key='Stack',Value='ETL'},{Key='Role',Value='Database'}]'
```

I am substituting all the variables correctly however the --tags-specifications is having some issue.
I tried below options with tags-specifications but none of them are working for me.

```
--tags-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=Owner,Value="Some_one"},{Key=Environment,Value="Production:Dev"},{Key=Stack,Value="ETL"},{Key=Role,Value="Database"}]'
--tags-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=Owner,Value=Some_one},{Key=Environment,Value=Production:Dev},{Key=Stack,Value=ETL},{Key=Role,Value=Database}]'
--tags-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key='Owner',Value="Some_one"},{Key='Environment',Value="Production:Dev"},{Key='Stack',Value="ETL"},{Key='Role',Value="Database"}]'
--tags-specifications, ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key="Owner",Value="Some_one"},{Key="Environment",Value="Non-Production:Dev"},{Key="Stack",Value="ETL"},{Key="Role",Value="Database"}]
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: what's your version of aws-cli?

Comment: I have below aws-cli version.
```# aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.30 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64 botocore/2.0.0dev34
```

Comment: After running command `python3 -m pip install awscli --upgrade` below is the version.
```# aws --version
aws-cli/1.19.70 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64 botocore/1.20.70```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what the error was or the aws cli version you are using. As you corrected the typo you had with --tag-specification, I am guessing problem may be the version of the aws-cli you are using.

AWS did not have an option to add tags during image creation until [December 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-machine-images-support-tag-on-create-tag-based-access-control/). If you happen to have an aws-cli version that is a few months old, when you run the command to create the image and add the tags, you might get an error similar to:

```
unknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=somekey,Value=some value}]
```

If that's the case, try upgrading your aws cli. Not sure how you installed it but if you used pip, something like the following should upgrade it, assuming you do have access to later versions:

```
python3 -m pip install awscli --upgrade
```

Comment: Seems like it was aws-cli version issue. Once the aws-cli version updated after --upgrade command everything was working except that my instance profile role do not have enough permissions. I am working on permissions. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaileshSutar glad that it worked. Please remember to mark above as answered.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `--tag-specifications`:

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $instance_id --name "$ami_name" --region $region --description "$desc" --no-reboot --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key='Owner',Value='Some_one'},{Key='Environment',Value='Production:Dev'},{Key='Stack',Value='ETL'},{Key='Role',Value='Database'}]'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with below combinations however it didn't work.
```'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=Owner,Value=Some_one},{Key=Environment,Value=Non-Production:Dev},{Key=Stack,Value=ETL},{Key=Role,Value=Database}]'
'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key='Owner',Value="Some_one"},{Key='Environment',Value="Non-Production:Dev"},{Key='Stack',Value="ETL"},{Key='Role',Value="Database"}]'
'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key="Owner",Value="Some_one"},{Key="Environment",Value="Non-Production:Dev"},{Key="Stack",Value="ETL"},{Key="Role",Value="Database"}]'```

Comment: @ShaileshSutar Why it did not work? Any error?

Comment: No error. Only returning unknown options in case of --Tag-specification however after pip upgrade command the error is gone.